# What is the framework for Google Colab or Jupiter Notebook?

Tags: .net, frameworks, google-colaboratory

We all know that the most popular framework for C# is .NET framework.

The most popular framework for Java is Spring.

Then, what is the framework that is using in Google Colab or Jupiter Notebook?

Comment: What do you mean? Like, a Jupyter notebook is just a (neat) way to organize Python (and other languages?) code.

Comment: So is it means that Jupyter notebook or Colab runs Python Code without any framework?